# Value error, truth error, ambiguous error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.6

When using this code

```
 for i in range(len(data)):
   if Ycoord >= Y_west and Xcoord == X_west:
        flag = 4
```

I get this ValueError

if Ycoord >= Y_west and Xcoord == X_west:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

then i use the above restriction

Any help on how i can keep my restriction and go on with the writing of my file?

Comment: What type are the variables?

Comment: @  ValekHalfHeart

The variables on the 2nd and 3rd column are coordinates while the 4th column is a index number

Comment: @George did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `Ycoord` and `Xcoord` are probably `numpy.ndarray` objects. You have to use the array compatible `and` operator to check all its values for your condition. You can create a flag array and set the values to `4` in all places where your conditional is `True`:

```
check = np.logical_and(Ycoord >= Y_west, Xcoord == X_west)
flag = np.zeros_like(Ycoord)
flag[check] = 4
```

or you have to test value-by-value in your code doing:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    if Ycoord[i] >= Y_west and Xcoord[i] == X_west:
        flag = 4
```