# Value error: truth value ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

Following up from here: [Conditional calculation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660792/conditional-calculation-in-python#25660792)

I'm editing this line:

```
 out = log(sum(exp(a - a_max), axis=0))
```

from line 85 here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/misc/common.py#L18

to this:

```
out = log(sum(exp(threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max), axis = 0))
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`out = log(sum(exp(threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max), axis=0)) ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I can see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482003/value-error-truth-error-ambiguous-error) answer that the error can be fixed using a for-loop to go through each value... but is there any way to incorporate it into quicker code? My arrays have tens of thousands of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression

```
threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max
```

is the same as `max(a - a_max, threshold)`.  If `a` is a numpy array, then so is the expression `a - a_max < threshold`.  You can't use a numpy array as the conditional expression in the Python `if-else` ternary operator, but you can compute element-wise the maximum using `np.maximum`.  So you should be able to replace that expression with

```
np.maximum(a - a_max, threshold)
```

(`np` is `numpy`.)

Comment: Now I get this error:
 `out = log(sum(exp( np.minimum(a - a_max, threshold)), axis=0))
TypeError: sum() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: You must use the numpy functions: `np.log`, `np.sum` and `np.exp`.