# Avoiding infinities in this numpy logsumexp calculation

Tags: python, numpy, infinity

Following up from [Value error: truth value ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661922/value-error-truth-value-ambiguous/), I'm editing the logsumexp function from here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/misc/common.py#L18

The reason is because:
1. I want to select the maximum value myself, it's not always just the maximum of the array
2. I want to put a condition to ensure that the difference after subtracting the maximum from each element doesn't go below a certain threshold.

This is my final code. There's nothing wrong with it - except that it still returns inifinities sometimes!

```
def mylogsumexp(self, a, is_class, maxaj=None, axis=None, b=None):
        threshold = -sys.float_info.max         
        a = asarray(a)
        if axis is None:
            a = a.ravel()
        else:
            a = rollaxis(a, axis)

        if is_class == 1:
            a_max = a.max(axis=0)
        else:
            a_max = maxaj  
        if b is not None:
            b = asarray(b)
            if axis is None:
                b = b.ravel()
            else:
                b = rollaxis(b, axis)
            #out = log(sum(b * exp(threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max), axis=0))
            out = np.log(np.sum(b * np.exp( np.minimum(a - a_max, threshold)), axis=0))

        else:
            out = np.log(np.sum(np.exp( np.minimum(a - a_max, threshold)), axis=0))
        out += a_max
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.clip` to bound the maximum and minimum values of an array:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> np.clip(arr, 3, 7)
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7])
```

In this example, values greater than 7 are capped at 7; values less than 3 are set to 3.

If I've interpreted your code correctly, you might want to replace

```
out = np.log(np.sum(b * np.exp( np.minimum(a - a_max, threshold)), axis=0))
```

with

```
out = np.log(np.sum(b * np.exp( np.clip(a - a_max, threshold, maximum)), axis=0))
```

where `maximum` is your desired maximum value.

Comment: do you mean, in place of `np.minimum()`?

Comment: @user961627 yes - I've edited my answer to include a possible solution.

Comment: I set `threshold` and `maxthreshold` to `-sys.float_info.max` and `sys.float_info.max` got this error: 
`out = np.log(np.sum(b * np.exp( np.clip(a - a_max, threshold, maxthreshold)), axis=0))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: Sounds like some of the elements of array `a` might be `None`. Are you able to filter these elements out of the array?